# Not getting email ID of user in React Oath Google

Tags: reactjs, google-signin

I've tried using React oath google for Google sign-in, but couldn't get the email ID of the user. Is there a way we can get that ?
Here is my code :-

```
const onGoogleLoginSuccess = (response) => {
    console.log(response);
  };
  
  const onGoogleLoginFailure = (error) => {
    console.log(error);
  };
  
  const handleGoogleLogin = useGoogleLogin({
    onSuccess: onGoogleLoginSuccess,
    onError: onGoogleLoginFailure
  })
```

```
<Button
                sx={{ width: "100%", color: Palette.accent }}
                startIcon={<img style={{ height: '15px', width: '15px' }} src={Google} />}
                onClick={handleGoogleLogin}
              >
                Sign In with Google
</Button>
```